# Stop sign flips in sklearn's PCA

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

I am using PCA to visualize the evolution of a high dimensional latent space of a network during the training process. For this, I'm using `PCA` function from `sklearn.decomposition` and visualize the latent space every 10 epochs.

The problem is that during the evolution, the direction of the PCA axis flips from one frame to the other. While this is not particularly important, it ruins my animated latent space progress. I was wondering if there is a way to stop sign flips.

Below are two consecutive frames of my animation with sign flip.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the `random_state` argument of `sklearn.decomposition.PCA`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I set `random_state` to `0`, but the problem still persists. Thanks though.

Comment: Also, for the future readers, I set `svd_solverstr` to `arpack`, so `random_state` was used.